# Logrotate is not working with daily and size

Tags: docker, nginx, cron, docker-container, logrotate

Im trying to use logrotate in my nginx docker container.
Im using nginx-alpine basic image.

Inside the container, I installed logrotate with: `apt-get update` and `apt-get install logrotate`. Also, I installed cron with: `apt-get install cron`.

I'm trying to use this configuration inside **/etc/logrotate.d/nginx**:

```
/var/log/nginx/access.log {
    maxsize 20M
    daily
    rotate 7
    create 644 root root
    dateext
    dateformat -%Y%m%d-%H-%M
    postrotate
          [ ! -f /var/run/nginx.pid ] || kill -USR1 `cat /var/run/nginx.pid`
    endscript
}
```

So, what i want to do is rotate every day, but if one day the access.log file has more than 20M, is has to rotate, so that day I will have 2 files. I don`t know if its possible do something like this.

My logs are not rotating at any time, not after a day or when reaching the indicated space limit. At least I would like to be able to use logrotate when it reaches the space limit.

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT 1**

Now I'm using a custom image with this Dockerfile to fix the cron problem, but it still doesn't work properly.

```
FROM nginx

RUN rm /var/log/nginx/access.log
RUN rm /var/log/nginx/error.log

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install logrotate
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY logrotate.d/nginx /etc/logrotate.d/

CMD service cron start && nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

I have tried setting the logrotate outside of my container, since I have a volume for /var/log/nginx/, but it doesn't work either, since the following line is not correct because nginx is in a container:

```
[ ! -f /var/run/nginx.pid ] || kill -USR1 `cat /var/run/nginx.pid`
```

Comment: I don't believe that the cron daemon will run inside a docker container unless the entrypoint to the container starts cron. Anyway, the established way to do this in Docker is to tell nginx to output logs to stdout/stderr, and do log rotation using Docker itself.

Comment: Hello, I have modified the description of the question explaining what I have tried. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't enough to run multiple services, because `service` depends on systemd being installed and running as PID 1. You need to do something like [this](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/).